# Yii Authentication if not user and change menu after log in

Tags: php, yii

Im new in yii , this is my question:

1. How to set up session for detecting if user is not log in .
2. After user log in show and hide div.
3. Not yet log in hide div.

**Menu bar / Navigation Bar :**

```
     <div class="rightPane">
 <div class="menuWrapper">
    <div class="menuItem">
        <a href="#"><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'HOME'); ?></a>
    </div>                        
</div>
<div class="menuWrapper">
    <div class="menuItem">
        <a ><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'CONTACT'); ?></a>
    </div>                        
</div>
<div class="menuWrapper">
    <div class="menuItem">
        <a href="#modal" ><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'SIGNIN'); ?></a>
</div>                  
</div>
<div class="menuWrapper">
    <div class="menuItem">
        <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl ?>/register"><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'REGISTER'); ?></a>
    </div>                        
</div>
 <div class="menuWrapper">
      <div class="menuItem">
          <a href="#" ><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'signout'); ?></a>
      </div>                        
 </div>
```

**Here I wish after log in "Sign in" and "Register" should be hide , then display a new div for "Sign Out"**

**Log in code from Controller :**

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$userpass = $_POST['userpass']; 


$record=Games::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$username));

if($record===null){
    //somethings
}else if($this->checkPassword($record->password,$userpass)){
    //somethings

}else
{
    $this->_id=$record->id;
    $this->_email=$record->email;

    Yii::app()->user->setState('id', $record->id);
    Yii::app()->user->setState('email', $record->email);

    //go to somethings
}
```

Comment: read and understand this from top to bottom http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/

Comment: learn to use netbeans ide with yii plugin https://netbeans.org/features/php/

Comment: btw, it is considered a good practice for full-caps labels to use normal (a-la "Contact") text and set css `text-transform:uppercase`.

Comment: @Cthulhu it doesn't matter uppercase or lowercase ... the display word is on other php ... the php named "labels"... this is just a variable to call it out

Answer (score 0):

1. How to set up session for detecting if user is not log in .

No need of session.

```
    <?php if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest): ?>
       <?php echo 'Hi Guest'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

2. After user log in show and hide div. & 3. Not yet log in hide div.

   ```
   <?php if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest): ?>
       <div class="menuWrapper">
         <div class="menuItem">
            <a ><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'CONTACT'); ?></a>
         </div>                        
       </div>
   <?php else: ?>

   <div class="menuWrapper">
       <div class="menuItem">
           <a href="#modal" ><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'SIGNIN'); ?></a>
       </div>                  
   </div>
   <div class="menuWrapper">
       <div class="menuItem">
           <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl ?>/register">
           <?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'REGISTER'); ?></a>
       </div>                        
   </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

Comment: 1. not work ... i paste on top of the page ... after log in still echo ... 

2. why flash message ? 2 is something similar to 3 

3. work but after login didn't show ...

Comment: now check for point 1 works, for point 2 i think you like to show notification to user or else some thing you like it to do please elaborately post it. For point 3 can't understand what you like to say.

Comment: `Point 1->`i didn't say point 1 work , login / no login also echo . `Point 2->`What I mean is logged in show "Log out" hide "Sign In" and "Register" ... I have mention on question.
`Point 3->` OK, it work . But after logged in I need Point 2 again.

Comment: Hi will you check now did you get the expected result

Comment: Sorry all not working ... `Point 1->` same result ,   login / no login also echo . `Point 2->`When Logged in "Log out" still hide "Sign in" and "Register" still show.

Comment: see the following file in your project directory hope this will help your learning curve much better `/project/protected/views/layouts/main.php`. In that there is widget class cmenu try play with that code some more time. You will get better understanding how to implement in yii.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63988/discussion-between-the-smile-and-gvgvgvijayan).

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer for Point 2: using user->id (reason I didn't use original provided login controller)

```
      <?php if(!Yii::app()->user->id){ ?>
    <div class="menuWrapper">
        <div class="menuItem">
            <a href="#modal" ><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'SIGNIN'); ?></a>
    </div>                  
    </div>
    <div class="menuWrapper">
        <div class="menuItem">
            <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl ?>/register"><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'REGISTER'); ?></a>
        </div>                        
    </div>
    <?php }else{ ?>
     <div class="menuWrapper">
        <div class="menuItem">
            <a href="#" ><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'signout'); ?></a>
        </div>                        
    </div>
 <?php } ?>
```